# Testlink: How to assign test cases to a role?

Tags: testlink

I know how I can assign a test case to a specific user. Is there a way to assign it to the role "tester", so that any free tester can execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used TestLink a lot but, as per what I have used it seems not feasible. Because you can assign test cases only to a Role-User (a person generally from Tester role) for execution and update, but it can't be assigned only to a Role.

For resolving your issue and for achieving what you are trying to do, you can create a dummy user (Passive user) which should not be existing in realty but only in your system like '[Community user](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)' of **SQA** and assign it Tester role. So, any test case(s) assigned to this user should be considered as **'Open for execution by any tester'** test cases and any tester can pick them for execution.

If you see that there is no such feasibility in your project to create such a user then you should assign such test cases to either QA Lead or Team Lead (one who is not responsible for execution) and treat those cases as **'Open for execution'**. This will not require any new user or anything else, such you need to inform all for this change of process.

Comment: A technical user is a good idea. Thank you